# Quick Multithreading Question

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

I have a startup function that calls a function which returns a boolean based on whether the set up is successful or not. True if successful, false if failed. I would like to start that function on a new thread and then check the status of the function: here is the code.

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(StartAdapter));
thread.Start();
```

My question is, how in that case would I check the return status of the startadapter method? Because my friend told me that I will not know the return status because it is started on another thread, and yet trying:

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(StartAdapter));
thread.Start();
bool result = StartAdapter();
```

would call the function twice, which is something I don't want either. Does anybody have some insight into this?

How in this case would I check the boolean returned from the startadapter function?

.NET 3.5

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the result. Why can StartAdapter itself not handle it?  But do use Tasks or the ThreadPool.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Henk Holterman. I need to know whether it's set up properly or not so I can prompt the user if they want to retry or just move on with the program. I plan to change a flag which will trigger the enabling of a button on the GUI which does just that; allow the user to retry that startup.

Comment: For the UI special rules apply. You will need WinForms Invoke or WPF Dispatch. A lot easier: use a Backgroundworker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for this case there is the `Task<T>` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28VS.100%29.aspx) that executes on the ThreadPool (for example) and lets you know the return value after it's finished

just use:

```
var task = TaskFactory<yourResultType>.StartNew(StartAdapter);
Action<yourResultType> actionAfterResult = ...; // whatever you have to do
task.ContinueWith(actionAfterResult);

// or:
var result = task.Result; // this will block till the result is computed

// or another one of the alternatives you can learn about on MSDN (see link above)
```

Comment: Note that if the `Task` finishes prior to the call to `ContinueWith()`, the callback won't fire.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Visual Studio C# where the .NET framework is 3.5, whereas the class you're referring to is only supported in 4. Thank you for the input though, do you know of any other ways?

Comment: @tf.rz Fear not! Read this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/aa1dd834-3c3d-409b-907e-196ee8f427bf

Comment: Thank you @dlev: I got this in the bag. =) Thanks for the answer CKoenig! Very useful class.

Comment: sorry missed the tag - but dlev saved the day